# Is it possible to create a SqlHierarchyId from a Hash Code?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

In C#, is it possible to create a new `SqlHierarchyId` from the hash code? I'm creating a tree view on a web page and I'm thinking it would be a bit tidier to be able to pass the hash code from server to client back to server than pass the string representation of the `SqlHierarchyId`. I know once I pull a `SqlHierarchyId` from SQL, I can call `SqlHierarchyId.GetHashCode()` to get the hash code, but I can't figure out how to create a new `SqlHierarchyId` from that hash code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: GetHashCode() returns the hash code (!), not a unique representation of an object, not some kind of object identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to map a hash back to a SqlHierarchyId and get the behavior you desire.  Hash codes are not meant to be unique, more than one SqlHierarchyId may return the same hash code.

There's a high level description of hashing at wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function.  Notice the first picture on the page illustrates a hash collision.

Beyond that, hashing is normally intended as a one way operation.  There isn't any method on SqlHierarchyId which can go backwards (and SqlHierarchyId overrides GetHashCode with its own implementation).  Even if look at the implementation of GetHashCode, there's not a way I can see to be able to recreate the state of SqlHierarchyId.  The code is looping through a binary represenation of the id and xor'ing values together in a loop (can't go backwards).